# The purpose of Visual Studio Database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a couple of questions about work process.
Recently I was entered to the new project with a lot of database activities involved. One of our repositories is Visual studio Database project and has all stored procedures, functions and so on inside it. We don't use it for CI, like Azure. As I understand we publish everything manually.
The questions are:

1) What is the purpose of the visual studio database project at all? Could you give me some points about it?

2) Should I debug and run all sql code in SSMS or in Visual studio db project during development process?

3) What is the purpose of 'publish' and 'build' functions in it? Are they able to break something in the existing database? How, why and when safetly use them?

I'll be very grateful for providing any tutorials, videos, best practices related to this theme.

Answer (score 4):

I love ❤ this project type.

**The database project gives you several things:**

1. It puts your schema in source control
2. It allows you to validate your schema
3. It provides semantic rename across objects
4. It integrates with Azure DevOps pipelines
5. It allows you to deploy incremental updates
6. It allows you to script pre/post operations
7. It easily deploys dev/stage versions of your db

**Is using it a good idea?**

Yes. I think it should be part of every project with SQL Server.

**Problems I have seen with it:**

1. It is not supported on VS for Mac

I use it in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Comment: More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272681(v=vs.103)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 4):

This is **SQL Server Data Tools** (SSDT). If you google that phrase, you will find dozens of websites that discuss it at length.  I have no preferred site for this--when I'm trying to figure something out, I read several sites to get a "composite" view of things.

The key thing is, SSDT provides is a state-based deployment methodology, as opposed to the more familiar migration-based methodologies. "State based vs migration based" is another good term to Google--all those website do a better job of describing it than I could here.

`Build` is roughly analogous to "will the code compile", e.g. is the syntax good, or are you referencing tables, columns, procedure that don't exist. As it's managed in Visual Studio, tracking down and fixing those bugs can be very easy. Well, tracking them down, at least.

`Publish` is, essentially, "take the database as defined in the code in this project, compare it with a target database, and make that database look like what we have in code". You feed the (table, procedure, etc.) definitions in, SSDT will write *all* of the necessary CREATE, ALTER, and DROP statements for you. Yep, tons of issues if there's data in the way, with various work-arounds to deal with it, but you don't have to make sure your five years of scripts are processed in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is the purpose of the visual studio database project at all? Could you give me 
>   some points about it?

At the current status it is good for tracking databases and see changes. It is missing a lot of functionality to properly generate delta scripts over larger scenarios (redgate has a product for this that is built on top). We use it to document the database status - which comes in handy to see how far certain databases are distinct from the documented state in a particular branch.

We use another mechanism for generating change scripts.

> 2) Should I debug and run all sql code in SSMS or in Visual studio db project during 
>   development process?

Ah, we have a very extensive integration test suite that comes from the API and executes a ton of backend SQL - that covers it for us. No need to spend days testing all SQL on every deployment.

> 3) What is the purpose of 'publish' and 'build' functions in it?

Tell me if you find out. I found them half-baked implementations. But then we do complex large databases at times - it is not ONLY about changing the db structure, but doing so in a specific way that transforms data, then inserts it into the changed databases.

What I did find out at times was that DB proejcts could deploy a fresh database including static data - but then, we do that with our change scripts often anyway.

It really is IMHO a hard thought out attempt, particularly i.e. compared to https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-change-automation/ the lack of multi step changes etc. make it not really usefull for our use cases.

MS does that regularly - i.e. you also have db migrations in EntityFramework (which we also do not use). Multiple approaches through different products.

Comment: So it is better to ask my teammates? I just wondering will it sound like stupid question or not.

Comment: No, it is more like that this is possibly the least used part of visual studio. Between all the alternative ways to manage database schemata and it's internal limitations I yet have to see anyone actually using it for more than documentation (i.e. to check in db schema into source control). See how many answers you get here ;)