# Create or Alter for Tables in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, create-table, alter-table

I have a table created on SQL server with minimal columns to start with which has data in it.

Now I have to maintain a SQL script with the create table command that runs every time the deployment is done. So I'm checking if the table already exists and only if not, I create the table -

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TestTable')
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT
);
```

If I expect the schema of the table to change frequently, how do I maintain this script easily to allow altering of the table, without having to do manual command execution.

The ideal solution would be to have CREATE OR ALTER for tables. But what is its best alternative?

Comment: *"If I expect the schema of the table to change frequently"* This is a flaw unto itself; a table's definition shouldn't be in flux.

Comment: I suggest you start using visual studio database projects. These automatically generate the correct change script and track changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60511228/the-purpose-of-visual-studio-database-project

Comment: @Larnu, although that may be true for a waterfall SDLC, frequent schema changes are common in the world of Agile, especially in dev environments. This requires strategy, CI/CD processes and tooling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually making sure that all my scripts are rearanable and with minimal damages.

This is my script template for tables.
I do have for stored procedures etc.
That with an ecosystem that deploys all the relevant script as a DB package part of the version.

```
USE [YourDB];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('<Name of the Schema, sysname, dbo>.<Table name, sysname, >') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET NOEXEC ON;
END
GO
    CREATE TABLE [<Name of the Schema, sysname, dbo>].[<Table name, sysname, >]
    (
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_<Table name, sysname, >] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON,DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) 
    );

GO
SET NOEXEC OFF;
GO
```

Reference to a similar [deployment system](https://github.com/crs2007/VerDeploy)